# How to add regionText to CodeRegionMode.End using CodeDom

Tags: c#, codedom

I’m using CodeRegionDirective to add start and end region around my code but when I used following line of code 
CodeRegionDirective codeRegionDirective2 = new CodeRegionDirective(CodeRegionMode.End, "End of My Function");
Then it added end region code like “#endregion” even if I specified regionText.I want my end region look like “#endregion End of My Function”. So please let me know how can I achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDom doesn't write the `RegionText` for `CodeRegionMode.End`. Here is the source code for the `GenerateCodeRegionDirective` method that is responsible for this:

```
private void GenerateCodeRegionDirective(CodeRegionDirective regionDirective)
{
  if (regionDirective.RegionMode == CodeRegionMode.Start)
  {
    this.Output.Write("#region ");
    this.Output.WriteLine(regionDirective.RegionText);
  }
  else
  {
    if (regionDirective.RegionMode != CodeRegionMode.End)
      return;
    this.Output.WriteLine("#endregion");
  }
}
```

From this you can see there is no `this.Output.WriteLine(regionDirective.RegionText)` for the `CodeRegionMode.End` case.